# How to create Handler which do not change HttpContext if not needed? (Asp.Net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, response, httphandler

I want create Handler which collect all URL, I check URL and then continue in "process". That means, if URL is `www.mysite.com/Contact` it call my handler and it continue in `www.mysite.com/Contact`. I don't want to call Redirect or something similar.

Problem is, it not pass content and scripts. That means all css, js and image files are not passed. For example I have empty `ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)` function and it block the files. Question is how to continue (load all files)?

This is how I register my handler

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MyHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="MyWebApp.MytHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I tried this

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
```

but it still block all files.

If you asking why I want to do this, because I want check Url and if everything is ok, it will continue, if not I redirect to controller. It is easy check Url and redirect to some controll or page, there are tons of examples with `context.Response`. Maybe I am doing it wrong and instead Handler there is something better.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it, but I am not sure if it is ok.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string page = context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
            bool continue = true;
            if ( page.Contains("Content/") == true
                    || page.Contains("Scripts/") == true
                    || page.Contains(".ico") == true
                    )
            {
                    continute = false;

                    if (page.Contains(".css") == true)
                    {
                        context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
                        context.Response.TransmitFile(page);
                    }
                    else if (page.Contains(".js") == true)
                    {
                        context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
                        context.Response.TransmitFile(page);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // interesting that pictures and audio files doesn't need set ContentType
                        context.Response.TransmitFile(page);
                    }
                context.Response.Flush(); // don't know if this is needed
            }
            // ...
            // redirection if page is not ok
            // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Deligating handler. and assign handler on application start.
use below code 
 public class SessionInjectionHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        ContextHeaders contextHeaders = HttpContext.Current.GetContextHeaders();

replace context code here
    }